# How do I compare and visualise two .wav files in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, audio-comparison

I am using Python 3 on Jupyter and I am trying to find out the accuracy of an audio file (has some noise) with the original one which has none. Please find the code, that I found online, below,

```
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dtw import dtw

#Loading audio files
y1, sr1 = librosa.load('data/dev1_female3_liverec_130ms_1m_sim_1.wav') 
y2, sr2 = librosa.load('data/dev1_female3_liverec_130ms_1m_sim_1o.wav') 

#Showing multiple plots using subplot
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1) 
mfcc1 = librosa.feature.mfcc(y1,sr1)   #Computing MFCC values
librosa.display.specshow(mfcc1)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
mfcc2 = librosa.feature.mfcc(y2, sr2)
librosa.display.specshow(mfcc2)

dist, cost, path = dtw(mfcc1.T, mfcc2.T)
print("The normalized distance between the two : ",dist)   # 0 for similar audios 

plt.imshow(cost.T, origin='lower', cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), interpolation='nearest')
plt.plot(path[0], path[1], 'w')   #creating plot for DTW

plt.show()
```

I am getting an error "No module names librosa is found"

Comment: did you install librosa module?

Comment: if not you need to first install it `pip install librosa`

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook so I am not sure where to write that.

Comment: update: solved the librosa issue

Comment: update: after installing librosa and dtw, I am getting error: AttributeError: module 'librosa' has no attribute 'display'

Comment: you need to have `import librosa.display` at the top of your script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202789/discussion-between-silentwraith-and-abhilb).

Answer (score 2):

First you have to install librosa ,
if you are using anaconda distribution of python then in anaconda prompt run `pip install librosa` or else run it your CMD .

Secondly `import librosa` on jupyter and then start working .

Answer (score 1):

After installing librosa lib.
its give issue on librosa.display so please **import librosa.display as dis** and use.
Also it will give issue on line dtw(mfcc1.T, mfcc2.T)
For this please below refer

1. https://github.com/pierre-rouanet/dtw/issues/18
   2)https://github.com/pierre-rouanet/dtw/pull/19

Answer (score 0):

..... Error troubleshooting

1.Python environment check

Please check whether the python environment is the python environment corresponding to the project code

```
20230112 11:06:30 ~ $ python3

Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug 11 2022, 13:36:31) [Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)] on darwin

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

\>>> import sys

\>>> print(sys.executable)

/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10

\>>> quit()
20230112 11:06:47 ~ $
```

2.Package check

Use the command "pip list"

If you don't see librosa, install it with the command "pip install librosa".

**Note on 2023-01-12:**

**The current librosa (version: 0.9.2), only python versions >=3.7,<3.11 are supported**

---

..... Bug I run your code and get an error:

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable DTW object

..... More error messages:

(venv_compare_two_audios) 20230111 17:57:56 compare_two_audios $ /Users/xxx/opt/miniconda3/envs/venv_compare_two_audios/bin/python3
.10 /Users/xxx/miniapps/compare_two_audios/compare_two_audios.py

/Users/xxx/miniapps/compare_two_audios/compare_two_audios.py:14: FutureWarning: Pass y=[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.], sr=22050 as keyword args. From version 0.10 passing these as positional arguments will result in an error

```
mfcc1 = librosa.feature.mfcc(y1,sr1)   #Computing MFCC values
```

/Users/xxx/miniapps/compare_two_audios/compare_two_audios.py:18: FutureWarning: Pass y=[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.], sr=22050 as keyword args. From version 0.10 passing these as positional arguments will result in an error

```
mfcc2 = librosa.feature.mfcc(y2, sr2)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/xxx/miniapps/compare_two_audios/compare_two_audios.py", line 21, in

```
dist, cost, path = dtw(mfcc1.T, mfcc2.T)
```

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable DTW object

(venv_compare_two_audios) 20230111 17:58:02 compare_two_audios $

..... code:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dtw import dtw
import os
import pathlib

#Loading audio files
y1, sr1 = librosa.load(os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent, "audios", "chunk0.wav"))    # 'data/dev1_female3_liverec_130ms_1m_sim_1.wav'
y2, sr2 = librosa.load(os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent, "audios", "chunk1.wav"))    # 'data/dev1_female3_liverec_130ms_1m_sim_1o.wav'

#Showing multiple plots using subplot
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1) 
mfcc1 = librosa.feature.mfcc(y1,sr1)   #Computing MFCC values
librosa.display.specshow(mfcc1)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
mfcc2 = librosa.feature.mfcc(y2, sr2)
librosa.display.specshow(mfcc2)

dist, cost, path = dtw(mfcc1.T, mfcc2.T)
print("The normalized distance between the two : ",dist)   # 0 for similar audios 

plt.imshow(cost.T, origin='lower', cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), interpolation='nearest')
plt.plot(path[0], path[1], 'w')   #creating plot for DTW

plt.show()
```

..... python environment

```
miniconda3 $ conda create -c conda-forge -n venv_compare_two_audios python=3.10
miniconda3 $ conda activate venv_compare_two_audios
miniconda3 $ conda install -c conda-forge librosa
miniconda3 $ conda install -c conda-forge dtw-python
```